# Draw many shapes on one Mapsforge layer

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, mapsforge

I develop an Android app that uses the [MapsForge plugin](https://github.com/mapsforge) to display a map.

I want to display 2000 points on my map. Currently I use `FixedPixelCircle` to do that which gives me a nice circle for each point that I can fill with a color I like to indicate different point status.

The problem is that `FixedPixelCircle` is a layer and I have to add 2000 layers to my map

```
getMapView().getLayerManager().getLayers().add(myFixedPixelCircle);
```

which leads to an `OutofMemoryError` or is extremely slow. I read that each layer needs about 3MB.

Now I am looking for a different way of displaying the points. Can I somehow add multiple shapes to a **single** layer?

Comment: Did you find any possible solution to draw **multiple** shapes to a **single layer**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the code of `Circle` - a class of MapsForge that displays a single circle in a layer. I just did not only draw a single cirle in this layer, but all the shapes I wanted.

```
public class PointLayer extends TileRendererLayer {
    @Override
    public void draw(BoundingBox boundingBox, byte zoomLevel, Canvas canvas, Point canvasPosition) {
        super.draw(boundingBox, zoomLevel, canvas, canvasPosition);

        for (Point p : myPoints) {
            //pretty much use the circle code to draw the point
        }
    }
}
```

See the [MapsForge Cicle code](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/mapsforge-map/src/main/java/org/mapsforge/map/layer/overlay/Circle.java)